# Get the values of two input range with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input type = range:

```
<input type="range" id="range_1" name="rangeA">
<input type="range" id="range_2" name="rangeB">
```

I want to get the values and put them in a function. 
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to select the input, thankfully you have separate ids on them,

Vanilla JS:

```
var element = document.getElementById('range1').innerHTML;
```

Here is a list of stuff you can then do with that element, like `innerHTML`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element